# Unable to integrate disqus on phonegap application

Tags: cordova

I am implementing Disqus in a phonegap application. I used the code below:

```
var disqus_shortname = 'myproject'; // the forum shortname we created
var disqus_identifier = 'disqus_thread'; // unique id of the thread we created

// SSO snippet

(function() {
   var dsq = document.createElement('script');
   dsq.type = 'text/javascript';
   dsq.async = true;
   dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
   (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq); })();
```

But I am getting the error [image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do it: https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472096-javacript-embed-in-native-apps

Namely, you need your code to live on an online URL, so the referrer is a real address, not a file:// one, which is the case in cordova/phonegap applications.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with the use of iframe.

the link to your iframe must hold the disqus code.

It works for me in android cordova/phonegap applications, but, facing issue in ios application.

ie., i can't close the browser and return to the app when i try to login in disqus iframe.